# Shared Hosting- Target class [Controller] does not exist

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel project that worked perfectly on my local computer, I uploaded it to the shared server and now I'm having a route error.

**Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Web\Back\App\departments\DepartmentController] does not exist.**

Route:

```php
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Web\Back\App', 'prefix' => 'app', 'as' => 'app:'], function () {
    Route::resource('departments', 'departments\DepartmentController');
    Route::resource('projectdepartment', 'departments\ProjectDepartmentController');
});
```

Controller:

```php
public function index()
    {
        return Inertia::render('back/app/departments/index', [
            'filters'  => request()->all('visibility', 'status', 'search'),
            'departments' => Department::orderBy('name')->get(),
            'users_count' => Department::withCount('users')->orderBy('name')->get(),
        ]);

    }
```

help Please...

Comment: is the correct namespace `Web\Back\App\departments\DepartmentController` ?

Comment: yes, Web\Back\App\Departments\DepartmentController

Comment: `back/app/departments` might not be the same as `Back\App\departments` on some systems

Comment: it seems to get auto prefixed: add a ` \ ` in this line: `Route::group(['namespace' => '\Web\Back\App', 'prefix' => 'app', 'as' => 'app:']`

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in my route, on the local server it was case insensitive while on the shared server it is case sensitive.

old

```php
Route::resource('departments', 'departments\DepartmentController');
Route::resource('projectdepartment','departments\ProjectDepartmentController');
```

Fixed

```php
Route::resource('departments', 'Departments\DepartmentController');
Route::resource('projectdepartment','Departments\ProjectDepartmentController');
```